# Proving that a linear transformation is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have the following question here.

> Let $C$ be an invertible $n \times n$ matrix. Show that the following map $\varphi$ is a linear transformation. You may use any standard properties of matrices.
> $$\varphi:M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$$
> $$A \rightarrow C^{-1}AC$$
> Show that $\varphi$ is invertible, and find its inverse $\varphi^{-1}$.

Finding the inverse is simple. It's just $CA^{-1}C$.  However, how do I know that $\varphi$ is invertible? I feel like this is very obvious but I am missing something very trivial.

It would be great if I could get some help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong. That's not the inverse. The inverse is the map $\eta\colon M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\longrightarrow M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ defined by $\eta(A)=CAC^{-1}$. In order to see why, just check that, for each $A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$, you have$$\eta\bigl(\varphi(A)\bigr)=A\quad\text{and}\quad\varphi\bigl(\eta(A)\bigr)=A.$$

Comment: Oops. I made a typo. I meant to write $CA^{-1}C^{-1}$. Why isn't that that the inverse though? Don't I also have to invert $A$?

From what I understand in your work, I am transforming $A$ so that means that if I invert $\varphi$, it's just the $C$'s that get inverted because that's actually the result of inverting $\varphi$. The $A$ is just "combined" into $\varphi$ right?

Comment: Let $\mu$ be your function. Did you actually compute $\mu\bigl(\varphi(A)\bigr)$ in order to see whether or not you get $A$? (Note: you will not.)